# asp.net how to send email with html tags as text

Tags: asp.net

I want to send email that has html tags as text

This is what I send

```
string sctipt = "<script src = http://whatever.com  type = text/javascript></script>";
message.Body = string.Format("script:{0}", script);
```

the mail is send but without the string `"<script src = http://whatever.com  type = text/javascript></script>"` because its coming as html tag and I need it to be send as text.

Any idae anyone?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three notes:

- Why are you trying to send scripts in an email? They'll be blocked by default.
- `string script` instead of `string sctipt`
- `'&lt;script src="http://whatever.com" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `HtmlEncode`

```
string script = "<script src=\"http://whatever.com\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
message.Body = Server.HtmlEncode(script);
```

or

```
message.Body = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(script);
```